# Language strings are not overridden in Joomla

Tags: overriding, joomla3.0

I am programming a custom template in Joomla 3.3. I need to override some language strings, so I have created a folder called `language/templates/mytemplate/language/es-ES/` and inside it, I placed a file called `es-ES.custom.ini`.

In template index.php file I placed:

```
<?php
  $language =& JFactory::getLanguage();
  $result = $language->load('custom' , dirname(__FILE__), $language->getTag(), true);
   echo $result;
?>
```

`$result` variable is true indicating the file is correctly loaded, but the strings are not actually overridden.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you enable Language Debugging in your admin area:

[image: Debug language]

you'll notice that even if your custom language file is loaded, other language files are loaded later, overriding your strings.

A different approach would be to create a file called `JROOT/templates/YOURTEMPLATE/language/overrides/es-ES.override.ini`. Then add the following to your `templateDetails.xml`:

```
<languages folder="language">
    ...
    <language tag="overrides">overrides/es-ES.override.ini</language>   
</languages>
```

This is described more in detail [here](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=629&t=639128#p2757196).